# docker BuildKit not printing ENV

Tags: docker, logging, docker-buildkit

I am trying the new docker kit to build an image since we need 2
different set of variables  my docker file looks like:

```
FROM python:3.7 as base
RUN apt-get update -y

FROM base as basic_build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./path/to/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV DEPLOY_TYPE=local
RUN ls -lrth

FROM basic_build as testing_build
# for testing
ENV A_VARIBLE_TEST=some_string
COPY ./some/files/ /app/
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "-m", "flask", "run"]


FROM basic_build as normal_build
ENV my_docker_test_var=see_if_prints_in_log
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "-m", "flask", "run"]
```

in Jenkins is been call as:

```
sh "DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --file ${docker_file_path} --target testing_build --no-cache ${WORKSPACE}"
```

but log doesn't show the lines of ENV been set

we can see RUNs the pip install, COPYs  but not ENVs:

```
#28 [basic_build 22/24] RUN ls -lrth
#28 sha256
#28 0.351 total 20K
#28 0.351 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5.0K Jul 14 16:04 file1.py
#28 0.351 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root   30 Jul 14 16:04 file2.py
...
#28 DONE 0.4s

#29 [basic_build 23/24] RUN mkdir /app/temp
#29 sha256:e1edb01f6c54b011bed2a1695a982985f6a418668509602436e17c0528dc17ba
#29 DONE 0.4s

#31 [testing_build 1/5] COPY ./some/path/ /app/
# sha256
```

but not when I set the ENV...
if I run with  --progress=plain
I still don't see ENVs... been assign  as if i do the old normal docker build (with no buildkit)

```
--progress=plain
```

such:

```
sh "DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --file ${docker_file_path} --target testing_build --no-cache ${WORKSPACE} --progress=plain"
```

I am missing something?  or the ENV don't show anymore? or are they not been set?
was expecting to see in one line something like:

```
Step 28/75 : DEPLOY_TYPE=local
 ---> Running in #####28a62
```

Comment: If you `docker run --rm your-image env`, does it include that environment variable?

Comment: yes, is i do docker run, and in the CLI i do env   yes they show up.   so how is like they are not been display in the log while they are been set?

Comment: i don't ever see ENVs  been print either with --progress=plain  or with out,        wonder why is that? with buildkit  with the old default docker they do show up